# Returning a serialisable object through oncreate

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building tictactoe and I'm trying to get java to restore the board on rotation. I'm pretty sure I've managed to get my onsaveInstanceState to work, but returning the serialisable object is turning out to be a hassle.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

This is my mainActivity

```
Game game;
TextView[] gameMessageIm = new TextView[3];
String[] gameMessage = {"playerone", "playertwo", "draw", "invalid"};
TileState[][] mainboard;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("mainboard", mainboard);
    for (int i = 0; i < gameMessage.length; i++) {
        outState.putInt(gameMessage[i], gameMessageIm[i].getVisibility());
    }

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initGameMessage();
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    game = (Game) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mainboard");
    for (int i = 0; i < gameMessage.length; i++){
        gameMessageIm[i].setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(gameMessage[i]));
    }

}
```

and this is the game class 
`public class Game implements Serializable {

```
final private int BOARD_SIZE = 3;
private TileState[][] board;
private GameState Gstate;

private Boolean playerOneTurn;
private int movesPlayed;
private Boolean gameOver;

//  classes' constructor
public Game() {
    board = new TileState[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++)
            board[i][j] = TileState.BLANK;

    Gstate = GameState.IN_PROGRESS;
    playerOneTurn = true;
    gameOver = false;

}

public TileState[][] returnboard(){
    return board;
}`
```

Comment: *[...]Turns out to be a hustle*, is not a pretty descriptive overview of your problem, is it?
To get people on Stack Overflow to help, your question has to be as informative and descriptive of the problem as possible. You did right to post your code, but that alone, won't suffice.

Also, what is the parent class or implemented interface of mainActivity? I could Google that, but I'm just pointing out what it is that your question lacks in quality

Comment: In onSaveInstanceState you are saving a TileState[][], but then you're restoring and casting it to Game. I guess the two object types are not compatible